# Powershell: Determine the current Physical network adapter in use allowing internet connections

Tags: powershell, networking, routes, vpn

I am trying to determine the physical network adapter in use through powershell.

I have some of the pieces for a function I am creating but have issues to determine the actual physical adapter in use:

1. With `Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Select-Object Name, InterfaceDescription, ifIndex, Status` I can get the physical network adapters, and if they are up:
   Here I get also the interface index (relevant later):

| Name | InterfaceDescription | IfIndex | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ethernet | Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V | 23 | Up |
| Wi-Fi | Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 | 8 | Up |

2. With `Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex <interface index> | Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'IPV4'}` I can get the routes for all interfaces (2 in this case)

The problem is that both interfaces have a 0.0.0.0/0 route for their respective gateway, so any of them can route me to the "regular" internet (let's say, google.com).

So how do I determine the actual interface in use?. I think that the interface metric in both cases can help me:

| ifIndex | DestinationPrefix | NextHop | RouteMetric | ifMetric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 0.0.0.0/0 | 192.168.3.1 | 256 | 40 |
| 23 | 0.0.0.0/0 | 192.168.1.1 | 256 | 25 |

So the Ethernet interface (IfIndex = 23) has an IfMetric of 25. As RouteMetric is the same for both, Ethernet Interface will take precedence, in theory.

This shall apply to connections with or without VPN clients (indeed for these tests I am connected through a VPN client) but:

a. I am not 100% sure that this may work every time.

b. What if the Route Metric is different for the interfaces?. What takes precedence: the ifMetric, the RouteMetric or a combination of both?.

Will be glad to read your comments or experiences about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of the metrics from my experience, however the way I usually get a definitive answer is to run the `Test-NetConnection` command to a URL or IP and the output of that command will list the interface it used. I use it to ensure traffic goes over our VPN adapter but in your case if you did a `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName www.google.com` it will return the interface alias of the interface used which you can use to find the ifindex and map it back to the adapter if you have multiple adapters

Comment: Hi!. Didn't think on that...looks way more easy with Test-NetConnection. I will make a few tests. Lots of thanks!.

Comment: Ok I have tested this.

Comment: Ok I have tested this. The problem is that when working using the VPN, a Test-NetConnection against one of the VPN resources (for example, a internal Sharepoint) will route through the VPN adapter (obviously) which in the end is a virtual adapter relying on the Physical adapter...